# How to fix a shapefile reprojected from sinusoidal projection to lat long?

Tags: python-2.7, geospatial, gdal, ogr, proj

I have been work in convert the MODIS Tiles Grid from sinusoidal projection to lat long projection using python ogr2ogr.

It doens't works well, the shapefile reprojected presents some lines that was not present in the original shape and it produces many mismatching.

[Link to donwload the original MODIS Grid Tiles](https://www.dropbox.com/s/11d01gn5gesw72p/tiles_modis.zip?dl=0)

Any suggestion to fix it?

```
# my code in command line
ogr2ogr -s_srs "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:/path/tiles_mod.shp" "C:/path/tiles.shp"
```

[The shapefiles reprojected](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qc9m4c6jpt7v85l/MODIS_reprojected_latlong_wgs84.zip?dl=0)

The original shapefiles in sinusoidal projection:
[image: Data in the original sinusoidal projection]

Processed shapefile using ogr2ogr.
[image: Picture comparing the global map and MODIS Tiles Grid reprojected]